# Command Prompt Not receiving Input Command From VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmd

Whilst bored, I had the idea to write a program (in VS 2010) to detect errors in my ipconfig (as my receiver's drivers are conked) so that I could reset it. I am attempting to use the following to do so:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\ipconfig.txt"
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
        ProcessConfig()
    End Sub
    Public Sub ProcessConfig()
        Process.Start("cmd", "ipconfig >" & Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\ipconfig.txt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

My problem is that when the command prompt opens, the ipconfig command does not show up in the cmd, and therefore does not run. It just loads a blank cmd instance. I have tested

```
Process.Start("cmd", "ping 8.8.8.8")
```

In a different program, and the command executes. Does anyone see a cause for this?

**Edit:** 
As suggested, I tried `/C` and `/K` before the command, but nothing changed

Comment: I love such specific and absolutely clear question titles like this! Anyway, try to precede the argument string with `/C` (or `/K` for testing)...

Comment: @aschipfl Sorry bout that, wrote this in a little bit of a rush before work. Edited, but in summary neither `/C` nor `/K` resolved the issue

Comment: The thing is: for running `ping` you do not need `cmd`, you can run it directly as it is an executable on its own (`ping.exe`). However, when using internal commands or [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), you need `cmd /C "{your command line}"` or `cmd /K "..."`. I don't know what `Process.Start()` expects exactly, but you could try to assemble the whole `cmd ...` command line in a single string variable.

Comment: If it does still not work, you could again try with two string arguments: `cmd` as the first, and `/C "..."` (or `/K`) as the second; try with and without quotation marks in the argument string...

Comment: @aschipfl Sorry for the very delayed response, but I have been busy with exams. The problem is not using ping, but rather `ipconfig`

Comment: It's the same for `ipconfig.exe` since it's also not a `cmd`-internal command but an executable file just like `ping.exe`...

Comment: @aschipfl To add on top of that request, I know the command arguments in cmd to send the output to a file is `command > path/to/file.txt` how would I do this with `ipconfig.exe`

Comment: The `>` is not a command argument, it is redirection! As explained [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680786/command-prompt-not-receiving-input-command-from-vs-2010?noredirect=1#comment86391472_49680786), you need `cmd /K ...` or `cmd /C ...` to process that...